# Managing transactions in Rails3 with MySQL and InnoDB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions, innodb

I changed my MySQL storage engine to be InnoDB so that it can manage transactions for me.

Is there a recommended or good-practice way or set of methods that people use to see a MySQL transaction in Rails from beginning to end, and ability to roll back changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only information I was able to find was this [link](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/InnoDB). Its part of the old Rails wiki and it mentions the support for transaction rollbacks. As far as viewing transactions, is the debugging output not verbose enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I've understood the question, maybe you mean something specific when you say "**see** a transaction".  But assuming you're just asking how to work with transactions in Rails - take a look in the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)